# $W^{m,p}$ not embedding in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Show that if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ its open set, $mp=N$, $p>1$, so $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ (sobolev space) is not embedding in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

I trying use contradition with Gagliado, or find a function. In book of lions he take the function $Log\left(log\left(\frac{R}{||x||}\right)\right)$ in $B_R$ (ball of center zero) but i cant see that its is in $W^{m,p}$.

Comment: which book of Lions, and where?

Comment: ...while I'm at it, I've answered a question of yours and you haven't responded. Is there a problem?

Comment: Sorry friend. I go look.

Comment: I was studing your solution and no find problems. Thankss

Comment: Well thats good, but where in Lions? Also, what have you tried? Since the function is radial, have you tried $\int f(|x|)dx = C_n \int_0^R f(r) r^{n-1} dr$?